# Light bending or custom rendering engine?

Tags: rendering, light

I want to create a short animation of the sun/moon rising and setting.
However I want to include some custom parameters to allow for the bending of light.

To elaborate, I am not talking about refraction here - instead I am talking about a competely new capability of light to bend in an arc that starts horizontal near the ground and gradually ascends into the sky (like an exponential curve). So basically I want to be able to describe how light should travel - not in a straight line but in an arc.

Is there a way that this can be done in blender or do I need custom work done?
If custom work is needed, who should I get in touch with for it?

Thanks

Comment: If what you want is to hire someone to do this, try the jobs board at https://www.blendernetwork.org or the forum for paid work at blenderartists.org

Comment: Can you include an image of something similar to your artistic vision?  Is there some measure of physical correctness?

Comment: Atomic, I do not have something to show you. As for physical correctness, we are taught that light travels in straight lines. Physical tests done recently show that light does not travel in straight lines but in actuality bends towards the vertical/upwards (noticable around the kilometer mark). I was just wandering if current engines support this and if not how we can get an engine to support this.

Comment: @conanDrum I would like to know where in the world is taught that light travels in straight lines.. Even in elementary kids know about gravity and what it does to light.

Comment: lol... Actully we are taught that it is affected by gravity but we can neglect it. Alll physics in school disregards this bending in our atmosphere. That's what I mean... I need an engine that allows for light manipulation, just like the one used for interstellar as mentioned below by Jerryno. (If I need to simulate a black hole for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope Cycles cannot bend light in arc nor Blender Internal. Only the renderer Interstellar was rendered in is capable of it as far as I know.

You can bend light with multiple planes with refraction shaders though.

Or you can code your own renderer.

Comment: The renderer for interstellar.... is it a rendering engine that can be used with blender? I want to bend light not to refract it because refracting white light will separate into a rainbow. The bending I want will only affect the perceived position of objects when viewed... not their colours.

Comment: @conanDrum no, refracting cannot separate single white beam into rainbow in Cycles. Cycles does not support dispersion. Interstellar renderer is not compatible with Blender.

Comment: Thanks Jerryno. So my only options are Cycles or a customization on the blender engine?

Comment: @conanDrum Yes, I would fake the effect with multiple invisible refraction planes - that would be the most simple approach to get the visual. You can also customize blender but that's a lot of coding to do.